mockito, mock new file or mock file.exists()
Prerequisite: Powermockito cannot be used and the original code cannot be changed.
how to let
File file = new File("xxxx");
file.exists() returns true.
public void testFile(String path) {
        File file = new File(path);
        if (file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("文件存在！");
        } else {
            System.out.println("文件不存在！");
        }
    }

@Mock
File fileMock;
when(fileMock.exists()).thenReturn(true);
fileMock has no connection with the local variable file in the method. So how do I make file.exists return true without creating a file?
